# Google Analytics Ecommerce Tracking error in Magento 1.5.1 CE

Tags: magento, google-analytics, magento-1.5

After upgrading from 1.4.2 to 1.5.1 my google analytics ecommerce tracking isnt working. Google tracks traffic, visitors, even goals… but the whole ecommerce section in google analytics isnt working…

I changed  in googleanalytics.xml in my template, as Ive read on some threads here, it didnt change anything.

Then I created ga.php override according to this post: http://magentist.com/magento_help/magento-google-analytics-issues/

and yet, google analytics works, but the ecommerce tracking in analytics doesnt work.

When I make a purchase, source code of my success page gives this kind of code right before the body tag closing:

```
<!-- BEGIN GOOGLE ANALYTICS CODE -->
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
var _gaq = _gaq || [];

_gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-XXXXXXX-X']);
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

_gaq.push(["_setDomainName", "www.mydomain.comindex.php"]);
_gaq.push(["_setAllowHash", false]);


(function() {
var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
})();
//]]>
</script>
<!-- END GOOGLE ANALYTICS CODE -->    </div>
```

If you notice it, the forward slash is missing before the index.php

```
_gaq.push(["_setDomainName", "www.mydomain.comindex.php"]);
```

I dont know maybe thats the problem, can anyone tell me please how to fix it?

I tried all the solutions I found in google without any success : ((

Here is how function looks like in my ga.php override:

```
<!-- BEGIN GOOGLE ANALYTICS CODE -->
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
var _gaq = _gaq || [];
' . $this->_getPageTrackingCode($accountId) . '
_gaq.push(["_setDomainName", "' . $this->getDomainName() . '"]);
_gaq.push(["_setAllowHash", false]);
' . $this->_getOrdersTrackingCode() . '

(function() {
var ga = document.createElement(\'script\'); ga.type = \'text/javascript\'; ga.async = true;
ga.src = (\'https:\' == document.location.protocol ? \'https://ssl\' : \'http://www\') + \'.google-analytics.com/ga.js\';
var s = document.getElementsByTagName(\'script\')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
})();
//]]>
</script>
<!-- END GOOGLE ANALYTICS CODE -->
```

I hope there is a solution for this.

Thank you in advance : ))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, just in case anyone else will have a problem like mine...

I tried all the solutions I found online without any luck... Today I just had to install another checkout extension ( I used "One Step Checkout" before and it had problems ) and now google tracks ecommerce transactions too...

so, if you'll have a problem like me, make sure the extension doesnt have any problems...

good luck! : ))

Answer (score 1):

Just as an FYI on the code - I'm not up with PHP, however with the Google Analytics, you want the line that you mentioned to read:

```
_gaq.push(["_setDomainName", "mydomain.com"]);
```

so get rid of the www. and the index.php completely.

Also, if you're just tracking between subdomains, and not tracking between two different domains, you want to remove the _gaq.push(["_setAllowHash", false]); line.